# Does jQuery Marquee work with jquery 1.6.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

Does jQuery Marquee work with jquery 1.6.4?
There is information here http://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/ that the library can use jquery >=1.6.4. 
This is my code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/tobia/Pause/master/jquery.pause.js"></script>

    <script src="http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jquerymarquee/jquery.marquee.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#marquee').marquee();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .marquee {
          width: 300px;
          overflow: hidden;
          border:1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id='marquee' class='marquee'>Less text here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, does your code work?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: jquery 1.6.4 - Release date of 9/12/2011. You have not upgraded yet?

Comment: My code doesn't work. And I need only jquery 1.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did the test for you

http://jsfiddle.net/aRW9Q/

```
Error says: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' "
```

The answer is nope, since `on()` was introduced in jQuery 1.7. Upgrade instead of using an outdated jQuery version!

Comment: Thank you epascarello. Maybe someone knows the other library?